# transformation for texture in Piston

Tags: opengl, rust, rust-piston

Piston has `draw_2d` function, and it can accept results from the function `image` which returns image made from the texture. There is a 'transformation' parameter for `image`, which most examples just takes from `texture.transform`. Internally it's a list of lists, like this:

```
[[0.0025, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, -0.0033333333333333335, 1.0]]
```

Example of the call is:

```
window.draw_2d(
    &e,
    |context, graph_2d, _device| {
    pw::image(
    &texture,
    context.transform, // [[0.001, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -0.0033333333333333335, 1.0]]
    graph_2d
);
```

I've tried to find what those values are defining, but failed. Docs just say 'transformation' without further clarification. What those numbers mean inside the array?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a linear transform from an (x,y) coordinate to a texture's (u,v) coordinate. Something like this pseudo code is happening.

```
with tansform [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]
For every (x,y) being drawn
    u = a*x + b*y + c
    v = d*x + e*y + f
    color = texture(u,v)
    draw color at (x,y)
```

Comment: Negative u or v?  Out-ofrange texture coordinates can be dealt with via repeating, mirroring, clamping. That is typically configured at a global level or on a per-texture basis.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) in the form of a [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix), which is used to transform the (x,y) coordinates of the image you are drawing. You could specify it manually if you wanted, but the typical usage is to use the methods on `context.transform` to perform the desired transformations; `context.transform` is actually a struct that implements the [`Transformed`](https://docs.piston.rs/piston_window/piston_window/trait.Transformed.html) trait.

The `image` function passes the transformation down through multiple nested calls, but it eventually ends up being used in [`triangulation::rect_tri_list_xy`](https://docs.piston.rs/piston_window/src/graphics/triangulation.rs.html#529-538) to generate the triangle vertices for drawing:

```
/// Creates triangle list vertices from rectangle.
#[inline(always)]
pub fn rect_tri_list_xy(m: Matrix2d, rect: Rectangle) -> [[f32; 2]; 6] {
    let (x, y, w, h) = (rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]);
    let (x2, y2) = (x + w, y + h);
    [[tx(m, x, y), ty(m, x, y)],
     [tx(m, x2, y), ty(m, x2, y)],
     [tx(m, x, y2), ty(m, x, y2)],
     [tx(m, x2, y), ty(m, x2, y)],
     [tx(m, x2, y2), ty(m, x2, y2)],
     [tx(m, x, y2), ty(m, x, y2)]]
}
```

Comment: If this is a transformation matrix, why it's 3x2 instead of 3x3?

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin Transformation matrices do not have to be square, and it's 2x3 (number of rows is listed first). That means it's mapping from R3 (3D x,y,z coordinates) to R2 (2D x,y coordinates). That is described even in the introductory paragraph on the linked Wikipedia page.